# Fade out audio with ffmpeg without knowing video length

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the following command line I use with ffmpeg to add an audio track to a video that doesn't have any audio track.

**ffmpeg -i final.mp4 -i soundtrack.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -shortest with_audio.mp4**

I am looking for a way to fade out the volume nicely at 3s from the end of the video. The soundtrack will be *always* longer than the video, but the video can be any length. Existing command lines I found require to specify exact timing when to start/end fade effect. I am looking for a way that is agnostic to video length, I just want the sound to fade out to start 3s before video ends.

Is there any way to do this with ffmpeg?

Many thanks in advance for answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ffprobe` to get duration](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Duration).

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of csv=p=0 input.mp4
```

Then use the duration as a variable in your `ffmpeg` command.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i soundtrack.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a]afade=t=out:st=$(bc <<< "$duration-$fade"):d=$fade[a]" -map 0:v:0 -map "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest with_audio.mp4
```

Comment: thanks a lot! that might work but ideally should be one line as I am running on Windows server and part of an automated process, not sure I can actually parse the data returned by ffprobe but I will check

Comment: @Flo The `ffprobe` output should be easy to parse. It will output just the duration (assuming no fatal errors occur) and look something like `108.501000`.

Comment: Is this possible without using ffprobe? Like with ffmpeg's `drawtext` you can do things like `h-text_h` to dynamically position stuff. I wish I could just do `st=video_length-5`